# HttpWebRequest with Form data and cookies

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

i analysed the headers sent when i logged in a webpage and see 2 headers , one 302 and one 200
i'm trying to do the same thing that the browse do, but in c# with httpwebrequest  i think that was be easy but i'm 2 days 
trying to do.
bellow here is the headers i captured when tried to login and the code that i'm using to simulate the request ...
i wondering if have someone who can help me , point where is my error and what to do...

REQUEST HEADER WITH CODE 302:

```
POST http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/Seguro/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fUniversusNet%2fNotasFaltasTotais.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www4.uva.br
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 455
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www4.uva.br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/Seguro/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fUniversusNet%2fNotasFaltasTotais.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wlo0ks55tanotwriaraapd55
```

WITH FORM DATA :

```
__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=7C9DFC57&ctl00%24FormularioContentPlaceHolder%24UsuarioTextBox=@@@@@@&ctl00%24FormularioContentPlaceHolder%24SenhaTextBox=@@@@@&ctl00%24FormularioContentPlaceHolder%24EntrarButton=Entrar
```

REQUEST HEADER WITH CODE 200:

```
POST http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/NotasFaltasTotais.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www4.uva.br
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 32020
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://www4.uva.br
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/NotasFaltasTotais.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wlo0ks55tanotwriaraapd55; UniversusNet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
```

I MADE THAT CODE TO SIMULATE THIS ACTION:

```
        HttpWebRequest x = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www4.uva.br/UniversusNet/NotasFaltasTotais.aspx");

        NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
        NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection();
        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();

        byte[] postBytes = ascii.GetBytes("__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA==&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=7C9DFC57&ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$UsuarioTextBox=@@@@&ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$SenhaTextBox=@@@@@&ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$EntrarButton=Entrar");

        collection.Add("Origin","http://www4.uva.br");
        collection.Add("Accept-Language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        x.Headers.Add(collection);

        x.CookieContainer = cookie;

        x.Method = "POST";
        x.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        x.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        x.Host = "www4.uva.br";
        x.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36";
        x.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        x.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://10.10.10.52:8080", false);
        x.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        Stream dataStream = x.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse y = x.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(y.GetResponseStream());
        var html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        richTextBox1.Text = html.ToString();
```

but the return is the same page i do the request , so what i missing?

Answer (score 1):

You probably getting same page with some error that shown in javascript! and HttpWebResponse can not show them when you getting page source.

Here are things that may help to send proper data to server:

**data string should contain username and password**

Check if you enter correct username and password when running program.
*username field*

```
ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$UsuarioTextBox%3D=USERNAME
```

*password field*

```
ctl00$FormularioContentPlaceHolder$SenhaTextBox%3D=PASSWORD
```

**Encoding**

also remember your browser will encode input data, so you should encode characters like '/', '=', '+' to '%2F', '%3D', '%2B'

```
string dataString="__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE4NzU1ODgxNTkPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8QZGQWAGQYAQU2Y3RsMDAkRm9ybXVsYXJpb0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlciRFc3RhZG9UZWxhTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmT14eU493cBliuPCSv6TJQbGDKjrA%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=7C9DFC57&ctl00%24FormularioContentPlaceHolder%24UsuarioTextBox=Username&ctl00%24FormularioContentPlaceHolder%24SenhaTextBox=Password&ctl00%24FormularioContentPlaceHolder%24EntrarButton=Entrar"
```

> URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet.
>   [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Instead of using

```
byte[] postBytes = ascii.GetBytes(YourDataString);
```

use

```
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(YourDataString);
```

**_ViewState**

> View state is the method that the ASP.NET page framework uses to preserve page and control values between round trips. When the HTML markup for the page is rendered, the current state of the page and values that must be retained during postback are serialized into base64-encoded strings. This information is then put into the view state hidden field or fields.
>   [ASP.NET View State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

It's better you get '_ViewState' value by sending GET request and look for its value in response.

Comment: @user3896400 as you said HTTP 3xx are code about redirection and not means any error. Check your response to see what server send back!